# coldfusion / browser timeout

Tags: coldfusion

I have a template doing a boat load of manipulations, I expect it to take 30-45 minutes to complete it's processing... I've had SOME success in setting my application and session vars to timeout @ 2 hr. and I've set my request timeout to 9999 (which should be 2.77 hrs)...

However - there seems to be a magic threshold - somewhere around the 20 min mark, my browser goes to a white screen (no output) and it appears as though the CF engine has also stopped working on my task...

can anyone suggest a reliable way to keep this process going - until it's done or my astronomical timeout occurs? in addition , is there any way to push feedback to the browser so it doesn't time out....I've tried cfflush, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: The problem may be with the task itself. Try and let the application run without the task running and see if you will get the same white screen and / or CF server stopping after 20 min.

Comment: I'm not sure i get what you're saying... I don't 'doubt' that the application vars are persisting for the allotted time... and the task is chugging along... as I can see the update times in my db for each record. ... it just stops at a point in time that is WAY BEFORE any timeout that I set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use cfthread to run the process in a separate thread and then on the page you are accessing in the browser, you could use javascript to periodically poll the system to check on its status.  For example, inside the long running process in cfthread, as you work through, you could set a application variables indicating that the process is still running and how far along it is, and retrieve and report those in the browser.  When its complete, you could clear the variables, or set a complete flag, etc, and your browser report page will be able to indicate that it is complete.

Comment: Sean - this sounds like a winner.. I'm trying it out - will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest refactoring the code to use a simple messaging / queue system.  It wouldn't take but 30 minutes to implement (or write a simple one from scratch!) and would provide a lot of benefits over and above solving this issue.

For example, its not a pass/fail for the entire operation.  If you hit a snag at say the 1.5 hour mark, you won't be re-doing the entire process again, only parts which fail.

Doing it this way there is literally no limit to how much processing you can do because you'll be adding and removing from the stack as needed.

If you give a little more background, I'd be happy to help you figure out logical divisions to make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a process running for that long, then you'll want to run it as a scheduled task.

I imagine your browser is the one dying.

Did you check to see if the request is still running?

`<cfsetting requesttimeout= "3600" />` will set the page to last for an hour. If you run it as a scheduled task, then session timeout shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: well - I've got the requesttimeout set to 9999...
I want the session - because I do a query and stor that in a session - to query against - as I don't want to keep hitting the DB... suffice it to say I need persistence of memory vars...

Answer (score 0):

Please do not store queries in session like that. Depending on the size of the query and the number of concurrent users in the system, you could easily run out of memory, causing some current and all subsequent requests to fail.

The database should be more than able to handle the heavy lifting. I'd hazard a guess that much of the processing you're doing in the application could be re-factored to happen directly on the database and save you a considerable amount of time.

Regardless, you should look into something like CFTHREAD as Sean mentioned, a scheduled task or a queuing system to handle a long process like this. The user most likely doesn't want to wait for the process to end before seeing the next screen. If they're told up front that the process is lengthy, they'll cope with waiting as long as they can move on to other tasks.

Comment: Foo - normally I'd agree with you - however this is SOLELY for me, no other users. and th ebulk of the work is NOT db - as it entails parsing and writing files - so there is a heavy file sys hit. the DB side just acts as a log. on that path - i suppose I could just cache the qry - but it was easier for me o fluch the session than the cache - or it seemed like it at the minute i wrote the code - but memory wize there should be no difference from a cached query and a session resultset.... thx. .. Im looking into the THREAD - that seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Generally the browser will timeout after 3 minutes of nothing being sent from the server. For most of these long operations I was able to periodically output a dot to keep the browser alive but when it came to some extremely long queries importing 20M records from a server side CSV file I had to think of another way.

cUrl was the answer.

So here's what I did.

```
<?
function get_page($page)
{
    $ch = curl_init($page);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION,'progress');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
}

function progress($clientp,$dltotal,$dlnow,$ultotal,$ulnow='')
{
    echo '. ';
    flush();
    return(0);
}



get_page('http://www.example.com/my_extremely_long_operation_script.php');

?>
```

Even with no output from the server, curl updates the download progress periodically.

Solved!